# Replace a line of text in a file using powershell 3

Tags: file, powershell-3.0

I am trying to replace some text in a file. Currently I am replacing IP addresses with:

```
(Get-Content $editfile) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "10.10.37.*<", "10.10.37.$BusNet<" } | Set-Content $editfile
```

This code works well here. However I can't get the code to work with another line:

```
  <dbserver>SVRNAME</dbserver>
```

Here is the code I have written for this line:

```
(Get-Content $editfile) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "<dbserver>*</dbserver>", "$DbSVRName" } | Set-Content $editfile
```

The code above should replace SVRNAME with the DbSVRName. Yet it does not. I know it's simple, and I know I am going to feel dumb afterwards. What am I missing?

While debugging trying to find a solution I found that for some reason it can't see the *

```
(Get-Content $editfile) | ForEach-Object { $_ -match "<dbserver>*</dbserver>" }
```

This code reveals all falses results.

Comment: Does it work if you escape your slash? `'<dbserver>*<//dbserver>'`

Comment: Er wait, You want it to replace SVRNAME? Use -replace 'SVRNAME'.

Comment: Chris It does not escape with a //. the SVRNAME can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` doesn't capture stuff in regex, you need `.*` and specifically `(.*?)`

```
$str = 'text  <dbserver>SVRNAME</dbserver> text'
$replace = 'foo'

$str -replace '(<dbserver>)(.*?)(</dbserver>)', ('$1'+$replace+'$3')
```

Output

```
text  <dbserver>foo</dbserver> text
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Making each item a variable to search. I did not know this one. Thank you. Do you have a resource on this idea/topic? I would love to learn more about the technique you just showed me.

Comment: [1] for playing with regex expressions. Here's a decent post on `-replace` regex [2], but the magic is mostly a regex thing, not PowerShell in this case. There are lots of regex resources, just do some searches. [1]: http://regexpal.com/ [2]: http://powershell.org/wp/2013/08/29/regular-expressions-are-a-replaces-best-friend/